# Creating an irregular point grid with provided row and column numbers in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, grids-graticules

I am looking to create an irregular grid of points via PostGIS, using the four provided corner (point) coordinates, and number of point-rows, and point-columns.

Four corners may or may not be perpendicular to each other (see image, 7 rows, 5 columns). Terrain is considered flat. What might be the easiest approach to solve this, within PostGIS ?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example image/sketch of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Automation of regular grids is pretty basic, bur, by definition, an irregular grid  would seem automation-resistant.

Comment: Please include relevant images in your question.

Comment: My approach was first creating four sides (ST_InterpolatePoints), then filling the inside, row by row. But not sure if this can be applicable in SQL/PostGIS limits.

Comment: It is still not clear from your question what you would like to have in the output, for example: 1) only geometry from points as in the picture, or 2) geometry from points and numbered columns and rows calculated from one corner (1 or 2 or 3 or 4)...This is important...

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko I need point geometry from "user-provided number of rows and columns". User will provide four corners' coordinates also.
Please consider 4 corner-points in above image, as user-provided point coordinates, all of the the remaining points are calculated. In picture, rows:7 and columns:5, these should be variable (ie, there can be 1 or 100 rows, or columns, if needed).

(Edit. User will provide four corners as C1, C2, C3 and C4. Point creation direction will be from C1 to C2, then the next row in same direction, like this..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are many ways to solve your question and this approach is one of them.

Create a fun function called `ST_RegularPointsGridOfCornerPoints`

```
DROP FUNCTION ST_RegularPointsGridOfCornerPoints

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_RegularPointsGridOfCornerPoints(
    geom GEOMETRY,
    r bigint,
    c bigint)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS  
$BODY$
WITH 
    tbla AS (SELECT ST_Boundary(ST_Union(geom)) geom FROM (SELECT ((ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom)))) geom) foo),            
    tblb AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id,
             ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2) geom FROM (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) pt1,
     ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom))) pt2 FROM tbla) AS geom),
    tblc AS (SELECT generate_series (0,r-1) as steps),
    tbld AS (SELECT steps AS stp1, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom1 FROM tblc, tblb WHERE tblb.id 
IN (2) GROUP BY tblc.steps, geom),
    tble AS (SELECT steps AS stp2, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_Reverse(geom), steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom2 FROM tblc, tblb 
WHERE tblb.id IN (4) GROUP BY tblc.steps, geom),
    tblf AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_MakeLine(geom1, geom2) geom FROM tbld JOIN tble ON true AND stp1=stp2),
    tblg AS (SELECT generate_series (0,c-1) as steps)
      (SELECT ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps-1)::float-1 FROM tblg)) geom FROM tblg, tblf geom);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run

`SELECT ST_RegularPointsGridOfCornerPoints(ST_Union(geom), 7, 5) geom FROM <name_table>`

See the result - Unfortunately something went wrong and it works not on all versions of PostgreSQL builds (For example, for PostgreSQL 14.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit and higher should work :-))... Remember my comment, its future hasn't come yet :-(...

As a consequence, for now, run the body of the function as a CTE and set the required values of columns and rows, for example, as specified in your question for your example.
The architecture of the SQL-code is shown below:

```
create table <name_table> AS
WITH 
    tbla AS (SELECT ST_Boundary(ST_Union(geom)) geom FROM (SELECT ((ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom)))) geom FROM layer_1) foo),           
    tblb AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id,
             ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2) geom FROM (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) pt1,
     ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom))) pt2 FROM tbla) AS geom),
    tblc AS (SELECT generate_series (0,4) as steps),
    tbld AS (SELECT steps AS stp1, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom1 FROM tblc, tblb WHERE tblb.id 
IN (2) GROUP BY tblc.steps, geom),
    tble AS (SELECT steps AS stp2, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_Reverse(geom), steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom2 FROM tblc, tblb 
WHERE tblb.id IN (4) GROUP BY tblc.steps, geom),
    tblf AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_MakeLine(geom1, geom2) geom FROM tbld JOIN tble ON true AND stp1=stp2),
    tblg AS (SELECT generate_series (0,6) as steps)
      (SELECT ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps-1)::float-1 FROM tblg)) geom FROM tblg, tblf);
```

The figure below shows the result, you should get the same one for yourself...

[image]

The figure

Unfortunately, I only fancy fun and customizable functions and they are not always simple :-(...

P.S. In the following questions, try to present the SQL-code and an explanation of what prevented you from getting the expected result...

---

**P.S.**

Everything is fine now, the geospatial function works as expected :-)!
Create Geo-SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_RegularPointsGridOfCornerPoints(
    geom GEOMETRY,
    r bigint,
    c bigint)
RETURNS TABLE (geom GEOMETRY) AS  
$BODY$
WITH 
    tbla AS (SELECT ST_Boundary(ST_Union(geom)) geom FROM (SELECT ((ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom)))) geom) foo),            
    tblb AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id,
             ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2) geom FROM (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) pt1,
     ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom))) pt2 FROM tbla) AS geom),
    tblc AS (SELECT generate_series (0,r-1) as steps),
    tbld AS (SELECT steps AS stp1, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom1 FROM tblc, tblb WHERE tblb.id 
IN (2) GROUP BY tblc.steps, geom),
    tble AS (SELECT steps AS stp2, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_Reverse(geom), steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom2 FROM tblc, tblb 
WHERE tblb.id IN (4) GROUP BY tblc.steps, geom),
    tblf AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_MakeLine(geom1, geom2) geom FROM tbld JOIN tble ON true AND stp1=stp2),
    tblg AS (SELECT generate_series (0,c-1) as steps)
      (SELECT ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps-1)::float-1 FROM tblg)) geom FROM tblg, tblf geom);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run:

`SELECT ST_RegularPointsGridOfCornerPoints(geom, 7, 5) geom FROM <name_poly_table>`

**(-: FOGS :-)**...

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: This is working exceptionally well, thank you very much !

Comment: I'm glad I helped you and others and thank you for the question... 8-)...

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to do this is to transform a square grid of points into the required quadrilateral.  Since the transformation does not preserve parallel lines, a [projective transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) is normally required.  This is complex to derive.
But this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863702) describes a clever and simple transformation of the unit square to an arbitrary quadrilateral.  The diagram below shows how it uses a combination of three vectors derived from the vertices of the quadrilateral.

[image: Quadrilateral transformation]

Here's SQL implementing the transformation, with an example quadrilateral:

```
WITH quad AS (SELECT 
  5 AS LLx, 5 AS LLy,
  10 AS ULx, 30 AS ULy,
  25 AS URx, 25 AS URy,
  30 AS LRx, 0 AS LRy
),
vec AS (
  SELECT  LLx AS ox, LLy AS oy,
          ULx - LLx AS ux, ULy - LLy AS uy, 
          LRx - LLx AS vx, LRy - LLy As vy, 
          URx - LLx - ((ULX - LLx) + (LRx - LLx)) AS wx, 
          URy - LLy - ((ULy - LLy) + (LRy - LLy)) AS wy 
  FROM quad
),
grid AS (SELECT x / 10.0 AS x, y / 10.0 AS y 
  FROM        generate_series(0, 10) AS sx(x)
  CROSS JOIN  generate_series(0, 10) AS sy(y)
)
SELECT ST_Point(ox + ux * x + vx * y + wx * x * y, 
                oy + uy * x + vy * y + wy * x * y) AS geom
  FROM vec CROSS JOIN grid;
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution, it appears both answers are solving my problem perfectly and equally well.